# Nginx Proxy cookies too large

Tags: vue.js, nginx, cookies, header

I have deployed my VueJs APP on docker container, but when I added nginx reverse proxy in my config file my cookie header become too large

my nginx conf

```
location / {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

location /api {
        proxy_pass http://[back-end-api]/public/index.php/api ;
}
```

[image: Cookies header]